# Performing SQL Injection (Interactive exercise)

Tags: sql, sql-injection, server-side-attacks

I am trying to solve an interactive exercise from my university. There is a field given for the username and one for the password. I have to login with my student ID (which of course I know but I dont want to reveal it here) without knowing the password. After trying some simple stuff I got the error message below. I guess this should help me, but I am not sure. Perhaps someone can give me a hint?

[image: Message]

Comment: A word of advice...always add the text of your error message.  Some folks may not be able to read the image you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track with your `' OR 1=1`, but then you have a syntax error because the string in the original query is closed again after you have already closed it. If you end your injection with a comment `' OR 1=1 --` that will tell the server to ignore the rest of the statement.

Edit:
I'm not sure why the comment approach didn't work, but even if you use the other mentioned technique of re-opening the string, I see now that still isn't enough - the precedence of the AND is higher than the OR, so you will get all rows instead of just the one with your username.
You could try instead

```
' OR name='myId
```

to produce

```
WHERE name='myId' AND password='' OR name='myId'
```

so it will match any row that has the correct username and password, or any row that just has the correct username.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately this didn't work. With your solution I get: SELECT name,password FROM login WHERE name='myID' and password=''or 1=1--'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try `' OR '1'='1` or `' OR 1=1 --`, a syntax error like this is because the query string in the code is not closed, so you should try to close it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. With your first suggestion I don't get any errer, but it tells me that the answer ist wrong..For your second suggestion I get the error message: SELECT name,password FROM login WHERE name='myID' and password=''or 1=1--'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1